# Retrieve 3d models from a server in unity

Tags: unity, 3d, server

I have 10 3d models which are about 8mb each..Now, should I store these 3d models in my apk or will it be wise to store it in a server and then retrieve it?.If so, how can I do that?

Comment: The trade-offs here are pretty obvious. If you store your models separately, your initial app download will be smaller, but a player might not be able to access all features/levels if they're playing online without an additional download. The person in the best position to decide whether this trade-off is appropriate for your game is you. You can download model files using the WWW class, like other file downloads. There doesn't appear to be anything in this question that requires expert answers...can you clarify whether there's something you're looking for that's not covered by the above?

Comment: i confused , which one do you mean by " how can i do that " ? sending model file from server to user , or storing them following the build ? (apk file)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using Asset Bundles in Unity
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-asset-bundles

this is the link to the official tutorial of unity describing to create asset bundles and load them from local path or a remote path